# Integer output formatting with print statement

Tags: fortran

I've noted that if I use `integer(16)` variables, when I use `print`, the output contains the exact number of spaces expected. Thus, when I use (some might recognize a project euler problem here)

```
    implicit none
    integer(16)::sum_sq,sq_sum,diff,i
    sum_sq=0;sq_sum=0;
    do i=1,100
       sum_sq=sum_sq+i*i
       sq_sum=sq_sum+i
    enddo
    diff=abs(sq_sum**2-sum_sq)
    print *, "The difference is", diff
```

I get

```
The difference is 25164150
```

as the output, but when I use `integer(8)` or `integer` for the variables, I get

```
The difference is             25164150
```

as the output. This occurs with and without the `-m64` flag and only on gfortran (my ifort does not seem to accept `kind=16`, a separate issue to be dealt with, but returns the output with the spaces for `integer(8)`).

Does anyone know why this occurs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already answered, you are using list-directed IO, which while convenient, is not completely specified by the language standard.  So you will find idiosyncrasies.   If you want to control the output will need to use a format.  Also convient is the format specifier "I0", which uses the minimum number of digits required to output the item.

As a side issue, "integer (N)" is not guaranteed to be an N-byte integer.  It is not the same as "integer*N", which is not part of the language standard.  Many compilers use for the kind values the number of bytes of the type, but there are exceptions.  In hindsight, it was a mistake to use integer values to designate integer, real & logical sub-types.    If you want to select types by the number of bytes, there are methods starting with Fortran 2003.  The ISO_C_Binding module of Fortran 2003 provides type designators such as C_INT32_T, C_INT64_T and C_INT128_T. The ISO_FORTRAN_ENV module for Fortran 2008 provides INT8, INT16, INT32 and INT64.

Comment: I do use the format standard with `write(*,*)`, but I was just wondering about `print`, as I have been using it for all the project euler problems that I've done.   On the side issue, are those Fortran 2003/2008 methods available in gfortran (version 4.6.3)?

Comment: The `I0` specifier was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 6):

This happens because you are using default formatting for the output.

`print*` is equivalent to `write(unit=*,fmt=*)`, where `fmt=*` means use default formatting for the output, which may be compiler dependent. Default formatting uses as much space is possibly needed by the data type being output, without making adjustments based on the value.

Consider following code:

```
integer(kind=4) :: a ! short integer for my compiler
integer(kind=8) :: b ! long integer for my compiler

a = 23
b = huge(a)

print*,a       ! small value, short integer, we expect spaces
print*,huge(a) ! maximum value, short integer, we expect no spaces
print*,huge(b) ! maximum value, long integer, we expect no spaces
print*,b       ! medium lenght value, long integer, we expect spaces

end
```

When compiler with gfortran, the output is:

```
          23
  2147483647
  9223372036854775807
           2147483647
```

The first line is a small number in 4-byte integer representation. Notice the spaces to fill up to the maximum possible size. Second line is the largest value a 4-byte integer can take. Fits tightly in output, no spaces. Third line is the largest value of an 8-byte integer. Fits tightly. The fourth line is the same value from the 2nd line, but in 8-byte integer representation. Notice the spaces.

This answers why you get spaces in output for default formatting. It does not quite answer your question exactly, which is why there are no spaces in output for a quad-precision integer. I don't know. Neither of my compilers (`pgf90 10.6-0`, `ifort 12.0.2.137`, `gfortran 4.5.1`) support quad-precision integer. Could be a compiler hackery. Someone might have more experience with this part, and hopefully they will chime in.

Answer (score 4):

List-directed output is processor-specific (note that Fortran standard calls "processor" what we'd normally refer to as "compiler"). Here is what the Fortran 90 standard says about list-directed output:

> 10.8.2 List-directed output
>
> ...
>
> Integer output constants are produced with the effect of an `Iw` edit descriptor.
>
> Real constants are produced with the effect of either an `F` edit descriptor or an `E` edit descriptor, depending on the magnitude `x` of the value and a range 10<sup>d1</sup> <= `x` < 10<sup>d2</sup>, where `d1` and `d2` are processor-dependent integers. If the
>   magnitude `x` is within this range, the constant is produced using `0PFw.d`; otherwise, `1PEw.dEe` is used.
>
> For numeric output, *reasonable processor-dependent values* of `w`, `d`, and `e` are used for each of the numeric constants output.

(emphasis mine)

The same rules are used for numerical values. The text in §10.10.4 of the Fortran 2008 standard copies that from the Fortran 90 standard so no changes in list-directed output were introduced.

As noted already by M. S. B., you can use the `I0` edit descriptor to print integer values with the least amount of space necessary:

```
! Note the space in the string
PRINT '("The difference is ",I0)', diff
```