# Spaces in fortran string output

Tags: fortran, space

I have the following Fortran 95 code:

```
    program write_test

    CHARACTER(LEN=3) :: str

    write(*,*) (' ',"""",'File'//trim(str(i)),"""",' ',"""",'Frequency'//trim(str(i)),"""",i=1,5)

    end program write_test

    !character*(*) function str(k)
    character(*) function str(k)
    !   "Convert an integer to string."
    integer, intent(in) :: k
    write (str, *) k
    str = adjustl(str)
    end function str
```

When I compile and run it, I get the following output:

```
" File1" " Frequency1" " File2" " Frequency2" " File3" " Frequency3" " File4" " Frequency4" " File5" " Frequency5"
```

Why is there a space between the double quote and the letter F?

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407232/avoid-newline-in-list-directed-output-with-intel-fortran-complier and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813340/integer-output-formatting-with-print-statement/11814170#11814170

Comment: The title is little bit unfortunate, because true leading space is more the space in the first column, reserved in list-directed output.

Comment: BTW, the `character(*)` valued function is something I would encourage you to avoid, it is somewhat misleading and error prone feature which is declared obsolescent in modern Fortran.

Comment: I know But I was just trying a short bit of a larger code to see if I get what I wanted. I intended to improve it later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For list-directed output with the * "format", the compiler has freedom to insert one or more spaces between the items printed. For more precise control, use a format string, as in the code below, tested with g95 and gfortran. You can use the i0 format to print an integer without spaces.

```
program write_test
character(len=3) :: str
write (*,"(100a)") (" ","""","File"//trim(str(i)),"""", &
                    " ","""","Frequency"//trim(str(i)),"""",i=1,5)
! preferred way is line below
write (*,"(100(1x,2a,i0,a))") ("""","File",i,"""","""","Frequency",i,"""",i=1,5)
end program write_test

character(*) function str(k)
! Convert an integer to string
integer, intent(in) :: k
write (str,"(i0)") k
str = adjustl(str)
end function str
```